# What kills a WCF service

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I'm troubleshooting a crashing WCF service that runs as a windows service. The service communicates with a database and throws an exception, which seems to be handled correctly

```
try
{
    this.sessionRepository.AddSession(session);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    var errorMessage = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "Failed to create a new session");                

    // some logging

    throw new FaultException(errorMessage);
}
```

If I'm not mistaken this shouldn't take down the service and that's what happens when I try to reproduce the same sql error error that I found int the customer's log files. I can see it in my logs, but the service continues to run on my machine. However on the customer's machine the service crashes during the call.

In the crash dump I could also find the reason string like this

```
<Fault xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
    <Code>
        <Value>Sender</Value>
    </Code>
    <Reason><Text xml:lang="en-GB">Failed to create a new session</Text></Reason>
</Fault>
```

So I suppose it also sends it to the client. However I don't know why the service always crashes during the call. Do you have any suggestions what I should look into?

Comment: try to catch the entire exception and also throw the innerexception

Comment: A Chuck Norris rotating punch!

Comment: The detail of the exception  is more valuable than the "Failed to create.."    Log detail about the exception.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not my code, I'm only trying to provide support to the customer plus I can't even reproduce the crash only the exception which I think I know the cause of

Comment: Why are you doing `string.Format` with a string that has no format tokens?!

Comment: I don't actually. It's not mine

Comment: Have you looked in the event viewer to see what additional details could be found?

Comment: That's a good idea thanks